# Windows "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess

I am trying to run a bash script from my Python code. I am calling the script in a subprocess like so:

```py
preprocessed = subprocess.check_output([
    'bash',
    '../Paraphrase_Demo/models/processing_utils/preprocess_data_givenBPE.sh',
    phrase, src_lang, tgt_lang, this_dir
])
```

Here is the script preprocess_data_givenBPE.sh:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

REMOTE_PATH=$4/processing_utils
SCRIPTS=$REMOTE_PATH/tiny-moses
TOKENIZER=$SCRIPTS/tokenizer.perl
DETOKENIZER=$SCRIPTS/detokenizer_v2.perl
CLEAN=$SCRIPTS/clean-corpus-n.perl
NORM_PUNC=$SCRIPTS/normalize-punctuation.perl
REM_NON_PRINT_CHAR=$SCRIPTS/remove-non-printing-char.perl
BPEROOT=$4/zhen/tools/subword-nmt/subword_nmt

text=$1
flan=$2
BPE=$4/$2$3/data/bpecodes

echo $text | perl $NORM_PUNC -l $flan | perl $REM_NON_PRINT_CHAR |
perl $TOKENIZER -a -l $flan -q | python3 $BPEROOT/apply_bpe.py -c $BPE | cat
```

When I run my Python program I get the following output:

```
Can't open perl script "C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos/Paraphrasing/Paraphrase_Demo/models/processing_utils/tiny-moses/normalize-punctuation.perl": No such file or directory
Can't open perl script "C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos/Paraphrasing/Paraphrase_Demo/models/processing_utils/tiny-moses/remove-non-printing-char.perl": No such file or directory
Can't open perl script "C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos/Paraphrasing/Paraphrase_Demo/models/processing_utils/tiny-moses/tokenizer.perl": No such file or directory
python3: can't open file 'C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos/Paraphrasing/Paraphrase_Demo/models/zhen/tools/subword-nmt/subword_nmt/apply_bpe.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have copy and pasted each of those paths into powershell and `ls`'d to verify that they are correct, but it still says it can't find them. What is going on here? This also happens if I run the bash script directly.

Edit: I've tried using backslashes in the path and received the same error. I also found this post: [Bash: cannot execute a perl script using an absolute path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318596/bash-cannot-execute-a-perl-script-using-an-absolute-path), so I tried using a relative path from the directory of my Bash script but it still says "No such file or directory."

Comment: To run a script directly you must have an association between the file extension and the program that interprets the script.

Comment: @MarkRansom, it's directly running `python3 $BPEROOT/apply_bpe.py`. The error shown is from Python, so we know at least that much is working.

Comment: The OP says "C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos/Paraphrasing/Paraphrase_Demo/models/zhen/tools/subword-nmt/subword_nmt/apply_bpe.py" exists, but the `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2) error says otherwise. "apply_bpe.py" isn't a reserved name (DOS device or trailing spaces or dots), so I assume there's a problem with the path. If this is the real path, then it's not a `MAX_PATH` (260) length-limit problem, and it's not a problem with a drive mapping since it's on the system drive.

Comment: @eryksun thanks, I missed that detail about the error messages. At this point the only thing I can think of is using ` \ ` instead of ` / ` in the file names.

Comment: @MarkRansom : maybe you can consider using os.path.join.

Comment: @gsr those filenames are being generated by a BASH script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of debugging, I found the issue. While the paths I listed exist if I `ls` them in powershell, typing `bash` in powershell doesn't just open a `bash` shell, it actually changes the directory structure. I think this may be related to the Windows Subsystem for Linux, but the result is that `C:` changes to `/mnt/c` once inside the `bash` shell. Replacing this in all my paths, I was able to run my scripts.